# GeoServer 2.18.7 Docker - CORS error

Tags: geoserver

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.127.86:8190/geoserver/rest/workspaces/potal_uiryeong/styles/rdl_rout_ls.sld' from origin 'http://192.168.127.86:8180' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
[image]

> 

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<!-- 
  THIS FILTER MAPPING MUST BE THE FIRST ONE, otherwise we end up with ruined chars in the input from the GUI
  See the "Note" in the Tomcat character encoding guide:
  http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding
-->
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

> 

var geoserverRestAPIUrl = geoserverUrl +"rest/workspaces/"+systemName+"/styles" ;
console.log(geoserverRestAPIUrl);

```
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var auth = "Basic " + btoa(GeoserverUserName + ":" + GeoserverPassword);        //HTTP Basic Authentication BASE 64 인코딩  //btoa : 문자열을  Base64로 인코딩
                
                xhr.open("GET", geoserverRestAPIUrl + "/" + layer_code +".sld", true); 
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);                    // 인증 정보 추가 
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
```

> 

"I'm encountering an error when loading the style XML. The CORS filter in \docker\volumes\geoserver-data_data\tomcat\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\web.xml is turned on, yet the error persists. Interestingly, on Windows, Geoserver works fine without any errors. So do I need to tune geoserver?

Comment: Please add the code as text.